# Automatic update to row number after deletion of row

Tags: sql-server, row

I have a table in SQL Server Express 2019 from which I read data by executing basic queries from my SCADA software. How can I create a column in the table containing a row number such that when I delete a row, all values in the column are automatically recalculated? My SCADA software can only execute simple, one-line queries. Is a computed column the answer? I started with an Identity column, but it does not update when a row is deleted. Thank you.

Comment: Use row_number function in a view and query the view.

Comment: If you can, create a stored procedure and call it programmatically after the delete operation. If you can't do that, you can create a trigger on the table to recalculate the values after a delete. Though I do have to question what on earth you're doing with that column...

Comment: The idea of an `IDENTITY` is to provide an always ascending value, *not* to provide a sequential value, nor to automatically update when rows that were created earlier are deleted.

Comment: That could be terrible for performance, @BrianStork . The OP would have to generate the key on `INSERT`, which would involve costs, and then *every time* there is a `DELETE` or `UPDATE` that affects the column, they would need to "fill in the gaps". `ROW_NUMBER`, as Stu suggested, would be a much better method which the OP can query as and when they need it.

Comment: Is there a business or legal reason that you can't have gaps in the numbering scheme? Consider just how awful this is going to be if your identity column is the primary key and that same value is in other tables. You would then have to update ALL the other tables. And that update will likely fail anyway because you just deleted the row with the new value. This screams of being an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Thank you, Stu and Brian. I hadn't thought of using a view. However, the need to add or remove a row only comes about once monthly. So the solution I am using is to simply use ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN, then ALTER TABLE ADD rnum INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL.

Comment: @john - no, this is not a good idea; the order in which the identiy values are added is not guaranteed and could change, so if you depend on this order, don't do it,

Comment: Stu, the order numerical order of the values in the new column ADDed is not important. I just need to have a contiguous set of numbers. So it sounds like this approach still works.